# field extension is Galois extension if and only if this extension are both normal extension and separable extension

Tags: galois-theory

I knew field extension $L/K$ is Galois extension if and only if this extension are both normal extension and separable extension.

I want know example:

i) normal extension but not Galois extension.

ii) separable extension but not Galois extension.

Can anyone help me?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i) $\mathbb F_p(t^{1/p})$ over $\mathbb F_p(t)$

ii) $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb Q$